# Non-invocable member SqlCommand cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Just started learning C# and SQL Server.

In Visual Studio 2019, I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConnectingToSQLServer
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLOCALDB;Initial Catalog=EmployeesDb;Integrated Security=True";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = SqlCommand()) // <- error is pointing here
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employees";

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    // int id = dr["id"]();
                    string FirstName = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
                    string LastName = dr["LastName"].ToString();
                    string email = dr["email"].ToString();
                    // int userlevel = dr["userlevel"].ToString();

                    Console.WriteLine(FirstName + " " + LastName);
                }
                dr.Close();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

In the Output, I am getting the following error:

```
error CS1955: Non-invocable member 'SqlCommand' cannot be used like a method.
```

But I do not know why.

What did I do wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: `new SqlCommand()`.  add the word `new`.

Comment: `SqlCommand` is a class, thus you need to create it with `new`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a compile-time error because `SqlCommand` is an object and you need to initialize it using the `new` keyword.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
```

Comment: I think it's better to just close this post as a typo

Comment: Thank you and everyone for pointing out my error.  Upon adding the word "new", everything works now.